# How to use Macbook Air's trackback to click Illustrator icons under the top icon?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mac

I want to get the icons behind the top icon, how can I get them visible? I am using Macbook Air without a mouse.

[image]

Comment: Why can't you just hold down on the icons the usual way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Photoshop, you don't need any special keys to access the hidden tools.

All you need to do is **click and hold**. If you click, hold and move to the right slightly the tools tend to pop up a bit faster.

Photoshop uses the <kbd>Control</kbd> plus a click to access hidden tools. Illustrator doesn't do this. Even if you want it to.